# Cannot find web/(un)secure/base_url entries in core_config_data table

Tags: database, core-config-data

When I installed Magento 1.8.xx on Windows, the database had the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` entries in the `path`, which I was able to change from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` to resolve the well-known 'cookie issue'. But in my 1.9.0.1 installation on my Ubuntu, these columns are missing. I have removed the Magento installation and reinstalled it, but still with the same result. Eventually, as advised by @benmarks in the answers, I simply added them and it worked.

But will anyone be able to tell me why they are missing in my new installation? Is it simply a bug, or because of my OS, or because of the different versions of Magento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These aren't columns. They are values in the "path" column of the core_config_data table.

If they aren't in this table yet, simply create them.

Comment: I was able to create them to resolve the 'cookie issue', but would you happen to know why they were missing in the first place?

Comment: Until they are explicitly saved in the database they will be determined from the configuration XML or explicit "if not set" logic hardcoded into the classes.